# How to view entire 5788 rows and 7 columns.?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science-model, data-analysis, csv

I want to see entire 5788 rows and 7 columns of my CSV data. I used below code and it is giving little data by stating [5788 rows x 7 columns] but showing only 10 rows and 5 columns in python prompt. How to get display of entire rows and column there?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("BusinessData.csv")
print (df)
```

Comment: I frequently use the command `less` in the `bash CLI`. Very quick for any size data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pandas has a max rows setting - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html

Though perhaps looking at a 5,000+ row csv in an editor, or a spreadsheet or some IDEs have a csv editor would be more useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can `print` all your rows by iterating over them and printing.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("BusinessData.csv")

print(df.columns)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(index, row.tolist())
```

Comment: It works ! Thanks Bruno.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the maximum number of rows displayed by PANDAS with the `'display.max_rows'` option. If you want it to show all your rows, you can do:

```py
    import pandas as pd
    df = pd.read_csv("BusinessData.csv")

    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', df.shape[0])
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following this article [How to show all columns/rows of a Pandas Dataframe?](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-show-all-columns-rows-of-a-pandas-dataframe-c49d4507fcf). I normally use the following commands.

```
# Display all columns
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

#Display all rows
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

#Display all elements in each col
pd.set_option('max_colwidth', None)
```